# Regexp in CLI flag value

Tags: go

I'm defining the following flag for my CLI in Golang:

```golang
var flags flag.FlagSet

phoneRegexp := flags.String("phone_regexp", "", "custom regex for phone checking.")
```

But, it fails when I'm passing the following argument:

```
./cli --phone_regexp='^\d{1,5}$'
cli: no such flag -5}$
```

While I understand that this is a parsing problem (encountering comma so it thinks its a new flag), I cannot seem to figure out how to escape (I tried adding a \ before the comma) or how to better describe the Go flag. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

### Edit

As I tried to make the question a little bit more generic, we couldn't reproduce the error. I'm creating a protoc plugin, thus the options are parsed like so:

```golang
import (
  "flag"
  
  "google.golang.org/protobuf/compiler/protogen"
)

func main() {
  var flags flag.FlagSet

  phoneRegexp := flags.String("phone_regexp", "", "custom regex for phone checking.")
  opts := protogen.Options{
    ParamFunc: flags.Set,
  }

  //...
}
```

and then the flag is set like the following (check is the plugin name):

```bash
protoc ... --check_opt=phone_regexp='^\d{1,5}$' my.proto
```

## Edit 2

I found the culprit [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/ec47fd138f9221b19a2afd6570b3c39ede9df3dc/compiler/protogen/protogen.go#L167). They are splitting by comma without checking if it's inside a string value.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this problem using Go 1.21.0. Using this code:

```golang
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"
import "flag"

func main() {
    var flags flag.FlagSet
    phoneRegexp := flags.String("phone_regexp", "", "custom regex for phone checking.")
    err := flags.Parse(os.Args[1:])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("phoneRegexp: %s\n", *phoneRegexp)
}
```

It behaves like this:

```
$ ./flagtest --phone_regexp='^\d{1,5}$'
args: [--phone_regexp=^\d{1,5}$]
phoneRegexp: ^\d{1,5}$
```

Everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I actually changed this example a little because my application is pretty specific. I'm creating a protoc plugin and the command looks like the following: proto ... --check_opt=phone_regexp='^\d{1,5}$'. I added more context in the question.

Comment: I'm glad you found your problem. It's important to accurately represent your code in your question; that helps ensure that you get useful answers.